# FSCL error on a simple example

Tags: f#, opencl, f#-interactive

I am trying to use openCL with FSCL on F# but I am obtaining some errors that I don't understand

```
open FSCL.Compiler
open FSCL.Language
open FSCL.Runtime

open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type gpu_point2 =
    struct
        val mutable x: float32
        val mutable y: float32
        new ( q ,w) = {x=q; y=w} 
    end  

[<ReflectedDefinition>]
let PointSum(a:gpu_point2,b:gpu_point2) =
     let sx =(a.x+b.x)
     let sy =(a.y+b.y)
     gpu_point2(sx,sy)       
[<ReflectedDefinition;Kernel>]
let Modgpu(b:float32[], c:float32[],wi:WorkItemInfo) =
    let gid = wi.GlobalID(0)
    let arp = Array.zeroCreate<gpu_point2> b.Length
    let newpoint = gpu_point2(b.[gid],c.[gid])
    arp.[gid] <- newpoint
    arp

[<ReflectedDefinition;Kernel>]
let ModSum(a:gpu_point2[],b:gpu_point2[],wi:WorkItemInfo) =
    let gid = wi.GlobalID(0)
    let cadd = Array.zeroCreate<gpu_point2> a.Length 
    let newsum = PointSum(a.[gid],b.[gid]) 
    cadd.[gid] <- newsum
    cadd

[<ReflectedDefinition;Kernel>]
let ModSum2(a:gpu_point2[],b:gpu_point2[],wi:WorkItemInfo) =
    let gid = wi.GlobalID(0)
    let cadd = Array.zeroCreate<gpu_point2> a.Length 
    let newsum = gpu_point2(a.[gid].x+b.[gid].x,a.[gid].y+b.[gid].y) 
    cadd.[gid] <- newsum
    cadd

let ws = WorkSize(64L)
let arr_s1= <@ Modgpu([|0.f..63.f|],[|63.f..(-1.f)..0.f|],ws)@>.Run()
let arr_s2 = <@ Modgpu([|63.f..(-1.f)..0.f|],[|0.f..63.f|],ws)@>.Run()
```

With this code when I try to use ModSum as

```
let rsum = <@ ModSum(arr_s1,arr_s2,ws)@>.Run()
```

doesn't work, but instead when I use ModSum2 works perfectly

```
let rsum = <@ ModSum2(arr_s1,arr_s2,ws)@>.Run()
```

The error I obtain the first time I run it is
  *FSCL.Compiler.CompilerException: Unrecognized construct in kernel body NewObject (gpu_point2, sx, sy)*
and if I re-run the fsi console says
*System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

The only thing I know is that the error doesn't comes from the use of another function since I can define a dot product function that works.

```
[<ReflectedDefinition>]
let PointProd(a:gpu_point2,b:gpu_point2) = 
    let f = (a.x*b.x)
    let s = (a.y*b.y)
    f+s
```

Thus, I guess the problem comes from the return type of *PointSum*, but is there a way to create such a function to sum two points and return the point type? And Why is not working?

**Edit/Update**:
Also with a record happens the same if I define the type as :

```
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type gpu_point_2 = {x:float32; y:float32}
```

If I try to create a function that directly sums two gpu_point_2 on a function works, but if I call a second function it raises the same error as using a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `[<ReflectedDefinition>]` on the constructor of `gpu_point2`:

```
[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type gpu_point2 =
    struct
        val mutable x: float32
        val mutable y: float32
        [<ReflectedDefinition>] new (q, w) = {x=q; y=w} 
    end
```

Normally each code that is called from the device need this attribute, constructors included.

Comment: No, I have tested it doesn't work. Also, I have done some search and results than it's not necessary to use [<ReflectedDefinition>] and [<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>] with a struct. if I don't use the attributes the second function works and the first one still raises an error. This can be seen on this [FSCL github example](https://github.com/FSCL/FSCL.Compiler/blob/master/tests/FSCL.Compiler.Tests/DataTypeTests.fs) and also there is another method to do the sum, but it doesn't use an extra function. Same happens if I use a record. I will update the question